# Angular anchor link does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, anchor, anchor-scroll

sample.html

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in items" im-move-hash>
     <td id="{{ item.id }}"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

sample.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('imMoveHash', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last){
     $location.hash(Session.getHashParams());
     $anchorScroll();
    }
  };
});
```

I already set hash parameter to Session.  ex). #1234

I expected $anchorScroll() would work and anchor link in the html would be fired, but it failed.

Since I thought this failure occurred probably 'id' attribute for each 'td' in the html was not set properly before $anchorScroll would be fired, I wanna get the event about completion of each id attribute set and then make $anchorScroll happened.

Does anyone know how to get the event of completion of html attribute setting? Or is there another reason why anchor scroll does not work in the html above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try wrapping in `$timeout` or passing element argument to `$anchorScroll`